# XML output is Duplicating Records VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, dataset, xmlwriter

I'm new programming so I appreciate if your response is simple and in the same language. I'm dealing with changing the file name system of my CAD application inventor. I have developed these simple lines of code to read and write using dataset, an xml file that stores PrefixValues and the sequence of the files.

To generate the new number, I have a class that controls all the events, and calls my other class and the sub-routines to generate the number passed by reference.

Everything seems working fine for different files, however, when I'm dealing with *mass saving*, like opening three files and generating numbers for each one of them, the output duplicates my records badly and I don't know what should I do to avoid this issue. This is part of the code.

```vb
Public Class NumberGenerator

    Dim invPresetsPath As String = g_inventorApplication.FileLocations.PresetsPath
    Dim xmlPrefixPath = invPresetsPath & "\" & "xmlPrefixPath.xml"
    Dim DatSet As New ConfigDataSet

    Sub NonDrawingNumberGen(ByRef NonDrawingNumber As String)
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(xmlPrefixPath) = True Then
            DatSet.ReadXml(xmlPrefixPath)

        End If
' First item from Row means the index and Second Item Means the Column 2 is the Non Drawing Number

' ***************************** ASSY AND PART NUMBER READ AND WRITE A NEW NUMBER ***************************
        Dim TblNonDrawNumber As Integer = DatSet.Tables("NumberingTable").Rows(My.Settings.PrefixID)(2)
        Dim NonDrNumber As String = TblNonDrawNumber.ToString("D7")

        NonDrawingNumber = My.Settings.PrefixSet & "-" & NonDrNumber

' Replace the XML File current value Adding a New Value 

        DatSet.Tables("NumberingTable").Rows(My.Settings.PrefixID)(2) = TblNonDrawNumber + 1
        DatSet.WriteXml(xmlPrefixPath)
    End Sub
```

**This is the subroutine in the main class that calls the previous code.**

```vb
Public Sub m_fileUIEvents_OnPopulateFileMetadata(ByVal FileMetadataObjects As Inventor.ObjectsEnumerator, ByVal Formulae As String, ByVal Context As Inventor.NameValueMap, ByRef HandlingCode As Inventor.HandlingCodeEnum) Handles m_FileUIEvents.OnPopulateFileMetadata



  For PartMakeComponentsCmd
            If Context.Item(1) = "PartMakeComponentsCmd" Or Context.Item(1) = "PartMakePartCmd" Then
                'does the verification of the extension
                oMetadata = DirectCast(FileMetadataObjects.Item(1), FileMetadata)
               CurrentName = oMetadata.FullFileName
                FileExtension = Right(CurrentName, 3)


                If FileExtension = "iam" Then
                    oMetadata = DirectCast(FileMetadataObjects.Item(1), FileMetadata)
                    Dim GenNumber As String
                    NumbGen.NonDrawingNumberGen(GenNumber)
                    oMetadata.FullFileName = oPath & GenNumber
                    oMetadata.DisplayName = GenNumber
                    oMetadata.TemplateFileName = "Assembly.aim"
                    oMetadata.DisplayNameOverridden = False
                    oMetadata.FileNameOverridden = True
                    HandlingCode = HandlingCodeEnum.kEventHandled



                ElseIf FileExtension = "ipt" Then
'This section tries to duplicate the record
                    For Each oMetadata In FileMetadataObjects
                        Dim GenNumber As String
                        NumbGen.NonDrawingNumberGen(GenNumber)
                        oMetadata.DisplayName = GenNumber
                       oMetadata.DisplayNameOverridden = True
                       oMetadata.FileName = oPath & GenNumber
                        oMetadata.FileNameOverridden = True '*
                    Next
                    HandlingCode = HandlingCodeEnum.kEventHandled
                End If 
 'Termination that defines that this only works for PartMakeComponents Command!`
            End If
            ' ******************************** PART MAKE COMPONENTS END ***********************************************
```

This is the structure of my xml File.
I dont know what means that tempuri org, but is created with my type dataset in visual basic.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ConfigDataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ConfigDataSet.xsd">`
  <NumberingTable>
    <PrefixID>0</PrefixID>
    <PrefixValue>61-03</PrefixValue>
    <AssyPartCountValue>2</AssyPartCountValue>
    <DrawingValue>0</DrawingValue>
    <DescriptionValue>Test Record</DescriptionValue>
  </NumberingTable>
  <NumberingTable>
    <PrefixID>1</PrefixID>
    <PrefixValue>61-02</PrefixValue>
    <AssyPartCountValue>5</AssyPartCountValue>
    <DrawingValue>0</DrawingValue>
    <DescriptionValue>This is another test description</DescriptionValue>
  </NumberingTable>
</ConfigDataSet>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Before you post your question look down at the preview. Your xml file was a mess. You can use the button marked { } on the menu ribbon of the editor to format code. Just select each section and click the button.

Comment: Thank you mary for edit it. Next time I post a question i will certainly follow your instructions, I tried to put those quotes but seems it didnt work.

Comment: It is not the quote symbols, it is the braces { }.

Answer (score 0):

Your code simplifies to a few lines of code

```
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        ds.ReadXml(FILENAME)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. how could I use that module section to read the specific record ("Prefix") from my cad software every time I press the save button? . Unfortunately at this point my programming skills are very limited, so I appreciate if you can give me a more detailed answer.

Comment: Dim prefixes() = ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Prefix")).ToArray()

Comment: Cool, with that line I can show my selected value I managed to make it work. And how could I replace that specific value? example currently i have 92 and I want it after saving my file to be 93.

And would it solve my issue of duplicated files?

Comment: ds.Tables[0].RowsAdd(new object() { "1", "61-02", "5", "0", "New Row"})

Comment: Thanx mate, It will add a new row, and I don't want to add a new row, I need to update that row. That xml is acting as a counter and store. So it reads the current value and then, stores the new value. At the same time, it works to populate a listbox with the current prefixes.

So I have for Prefix 61-02 saved X amount of assys or parts and Y amount of Y drawings.

I was previously using a txt file to read on prefix, generate numbers and replace them, it worked like a charm and super fast. But I didn't have the capability to manage simple data in the same way as with this dataset and xml.

Comment: I believe that I need to replace that value in a more straightforward way in the similar way i was doing with the txt file.

'DatSet.Tables("NumberingTable").Rows(My.Settings.PrefixID)(2) = TblNonDrawNumber + 1
        'DatSet.WriteXml(xmlPrefixPath)' I believe this is the part of the code that is stuffing it up, too slow to handle it.

Comment: You can search the table for a row(s) and then change the data : dim row as DataRow() = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Prefix") = "1").ToArray()  the returned value is ByRef so if you change the row data the table value will change.

Comment: Do benchmarking to determine if the what is causing the long time.  I suspect it is something with the write.  Try writing to local c drive to see if it is faster.  You may have a virus checking program that is slowing down the writes or using a slow driver or even a badly fragmented drive.

Comment: OK, Now im completly blocked.... I don't know how to use that datarow. I cannot use my variable Dim Ds As New ConfigDataSet as it will send me an error, then i have to use a datatable and read that data table I really don't know how to do that.

With the previous code you gave me I managed to show the value i want to use and then increment it by 1. With this

Dim prefixes() = Dt.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("AssyPartCountValue")).ToArray()

and then pass it by reference somewhere else with this

NonDrawingNumber = prefixes(My.Settings.PrefixID)

Comment: Once you have a DataRow you can read write like your code.  You can use row[number][index] or row[number][name] for the columns.  The number is the index number that WHERE returns for number of matches, not the actual row number.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely correct, Dataset wasn't able to handle the mass saving option, nor datarow or datatable. I had to do it in the hard way and it's by editing the xml directly as it was any simple document. This is the code, I know it can be simplified. But it worked like that for me marvellous and super fast. 3 Days of headache.

```
 `Dim docPrefixSettings As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument`

    `docPrefixSettings.Load(xmlPrefixPath)`


    ' Selects the root of the XML
    `Dim elm As XmlElement = docPrefixSettings.DocumentElement`

    ' Selects the Row Item in this case is the defined by the selected settings
    `Dim Table As XmlNodeList = elm.ChildNodes`
    `Dim Values As XmlNode = Table.Item(My.Settings.PrefixID)`

    ' Selects the Item inside the Row
    `Dim AssyCurrentValue As XmlNode = Values.ChildNodes.Item(2)`

    ' Selects the Variable CurrentValue and Assigns the Value of the Inner Text
    `Dim CurrentValue As Integer = AssyCurrentValue.InnerText`

    ' Defines the String in Formated Number for the Obtained Value
    `Dim NonDrNumber As String = CurrentValue.ToString("D7")`

    ' THIS IS THE PART OR ASSEMBLY NUMBER!!!!!
    `NonDrawingNumber = My.Settings.PrefixSet & "-" & NonDrNumber`



    ' Changing the old value and adding 1
    ' Defines the new Value for the current Assy or Part Number
    `Dim NewValue As Integer = AssyCurrentValue.InnerText + 1`

    'Sets the value to be use in the following one
    `AssyCurrentValue.InnerText = NewValue`

    'Saves the Document with this new value
    `docPrefixSettings.Save(xmlPrefixPath)`
```